# mysql lock gap when using secondary index

Tags: mysql, transactions

Suppose that an InnoDB table vv has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `vv` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idx` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `vv_idx` (`idx`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and

```
mysql> select * from vv;
+----+------+
| id | idx  |
+----+------+
|  1 |   20 |
|  2 |   25 |
|  3 |   30 |
```

Now suppose that two sessions perform the following operations in order:

session1:

```
mysql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete from vv where idx = 25;
Query OK, 1 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

session2:

```
mysql> begin;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete from vv where idx = 19;
Query OK, 1 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delete from vv where idx = 20;  -- blocked

mysql> delete from vv where idx = 29;  -- blocked

mysql> delete from vv where idx = 30;
Query OK, 1 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

The lock gap is `[20, 30)`, why? And how does mysql use secondary index to search ?

Your help is much appreciated.